# Windows cannot use BitLocker

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I have a Windows 10 machine in a domain, and I am trying to turn on the BitLocker on C drive. It give me an error on compatible TPM found. In the Local Group Policy, I enabled to use BitLocker to use without the TPM. But it still gives me the same error.

Any clue, how to overcome this?

Comment: Could you please review the requirements on the Microsoft page [Bitlocker subheading System requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/bitlocker/bitlocker-overview#system-requirements) to confirm that the computer meets the requirements? This would also include a physical TPM chip.

Comment: There might be a domain policy requiring a TPM chip for BitLocker. Contact your domain administrator for help deploying BitLocker. You could lock yourself out of your own machine if you don't plan appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my machine and found the following solution:

The group policy of your machine needs to be changed to allow for bitlocker to run without TPM enabled.

To do this, click on the the `Windows button` and hit `R` to run to start the run command.

Type `gpedit.msc` into the run command box and hit enter.

Navigate to the following:
`Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > BitLocker Drive Encryption > Operating System Drives` in the left pane.

Double-click the “Require additional authentication at startup” option.

Select “Enabled” at the top of the window, and ensure the “Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM" checkbox is enabled here.

[image]

Comment: You might want to read the question again, the author specifically indicates, they already configured group policy in question.

Comment: Ahh I missed that part @Ramhound. The only thing I can think of is updating the BIOS to the latest version for their machine. Could it be explained why they original poster doesn't want to use TPM?